# How to find if there is a point in a vector with sudden decrease in value after that in R

Tags: r

I have a set of vectors in `R` and want to find is there any index for the that the values suddenly decrease after that. for example: [1739,11560,20257,4,2,0,5] in this example the output should be "4".
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `diff` to find the difference of adjacent elements in the `vector`, convert it to a logical vector with (`< 0`) and find the index of the first TRUE value with `which.max`

```
which.max(c(FALSE, diff(v1) < 0))
#[1] 4
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(1739, 11560, 20257, 4, 2, 0, 5)
```

Comment: great use of `which.max`...it avoids having to index `which`. But what happens if say `v2 <- c(1739, 11560, 20257, 4, 2, 0, 5, -10956, -3248)`? Maybe OP doesn't need it but it is not clear (nor is "I have a set of vectors..."), but still, It'd be interesting to see If it can be done as easily

Comment: Maybe something like `m1 <- cbind(lag(c(FALSE, diff(v2) < 0)), c(FALSE, diff(v2) < 0)); which(m1[,1] - m1[,2] == -1)`